# Confused about assinging list items to vars in python

Tags: python, list, variables, reference

Say I have a list:

```
L = [1,2,3]
```

and I assigned `L[0]` to a variable `a`

```
a = L[0]
```

then if I change `a`, it won't affect `L`.

```
a = a + 1
print L # [1,2,3] not affected
```

Why is this happening? isn't python passing everything around with references? I thought that `a` is pointing to `L[0]`

Comment: Take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference, I think there you can find the solution for your question, otherwise let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L[0]` is a name, and when you create the list `L`, you assign an object to that name, the integer 1.  `a` is also a name, and when you assign a as in `a = L[0]`, you make `a` to point to the same object that `L[0]` points to.

But when you later do `a = a + 1`, this is *another assignment*.  You are not modifying the object that `a` points to -- the `=` sign can't do that.  You are creating a new object, the integer 2, and assigning that to `a`.

So in the end, you have two objects in memory; one is referred to by `L[0]` and the other is referred to by `a`.

Integers are immutable, which means that there is no possible way to change the properties of the objects in this example; however, that's not salient in this example exactly, because even if the object was mutable it wouldn't change the fact that you're doing assignment (with the `=` sign).  In a case where the object in question was mutable, you could theoretically change the properties of the object when it is still referenced by `L[0]` and `a`, instead of doing any additional assignment with `=` as you are doing.  At that point, you would see the properties change regardless of which name you used to inspect the object.

Comment: I think it's not exactly accurate to say that `=` can't modify anything. While it's true that `L[0] = "foo"` replaces the old value in `L[0]` without modifying it, it does mutate the list `L`.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for pointing that out.  It's not that `=` can't modify anything, because assignment can itself modify objects.  But `=` can't modify the object referenced by the name it is operating on.  It doesn't need to dereference the name itself at all --though in the case of `L[0]` or e.g. `obj.foo`, `L` or `obj` must be dereferenced in order to do the assignment.  (If the name in question is a property, then there could be something tricky happening where the owner of the property is doing straight-up mutation in lieu of assignment, but that's a fairly advanced discussion topic.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `a` and `L[0]` are references to an immutable object, so changing any one of them won't affect the other references:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, [3]]
>>> a = L[0]
>>> a = a + 1
```

`a` now points to a new object, while `L[0]` still points to the same object.

```
>>> a, L[0]   
(2, 1)
```

Now in this case `b` and `L[2]` are references to a mutable object(`list`), any in-place operation on them will affect all the references:

```
>>> b = L[2]
>>> b.append(4)  #list.append is an in-place operation
>>> b, L[2]
([3, 4], [3, 4])

>>> b = b + [5]  #mutable object, but not an in-place operation 
>>> b            #b is assigned to new list object
[3, 4, 5]
>>> L[2]         #L[2] is unchanged
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `L[0]` in your case is [immutable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), changing `a` doesn't affect the value of `L[0]`. When you change `a`, the **new** object is created and `a` starts to pointing to it.

See what happens if `L[0]` is of a mutable type:

```
>>> L = [[1],2,3]
>>> a = L[0]
>>> a.append(2)
>>> L
[[1, 2], 2, 3]
```

In this case `a` and `L[0]` both point to the same object.

Also see [Raymond Hettinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15697476/771848) in the [relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Change the assignment to:

```
a = L
```

then when you change L as:

```
L[0] += 1
```

you will see that a also changes. This is the reference magic.